# combining methods with same flow in controller.

Tags: spring, oop

Method 1.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getProfessor")
public @ResponseBody List<Object> getMember(HttpServletRequest request){
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   HashMap user = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("USER_INFO");

   Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   param.put("phone", (String)user.get("PHONE");

   ReportManager  manager = new ReportManager();

   List<Object> list = manager.getProfessor(param);
}
```

Method 2.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMember")
public @ResponseBody List<Object> getMember(HttpServletRequest request){
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   HashMap user = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("USER_INFO");

   Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   param.put("phone", (String)user.get("PHONE");

   ReportManager  manager = new ReportManager();

   List<Object> list = manager.getMember(param);
}
```

The code above briefly describe  how I get list of members and professors.
The two methods have exactly same code flow except URL and the bottom-most methods. As you know, one of core principles in OOP is 'combine repeating problems'.   So, the point is that I want to combine these method into one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Map<String, Object> getParams(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    HashMap user = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("USER_INFO");

    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("phone", (String)user.get("PHONE");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/getProfessor")
public @ResponseBody List<Object> getMember(HttpServletRequest request){

    ReportManager  manager = new ReportManager();

    List<Object> list = manager.getProfessor(this.getParams(request));
}

@RequestMapping(value="/getProfessor")
public @ResponseBody List<Object> getMember(HttpServletRequest request){

    ReportManager  manager = new ReportManager();

    List<Object> list = manager.getProfessor(this.getParams(request));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the url to a more generic url like `/getUser`.

Pass an additional `TYPE` param like `PROFESSOR/MEMBER` in the request. Depending on the  `TYPE` you can query two different methods in your controller method.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with you, as per DRY coding principle duplicating the same code is not recommended.
Either you can use single RequestMapping with some kind of query parameter, OR 
move the common code to different method, and invoke it from two methods.